# How to combine two lists into a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I combine two lists into a dictionary in Python?

For example:

```python
a_list = ['h1','a'],['h2' ,'a2']
b_list = ['hi', 'hello']
```

My output should be:

```python
output = {'hi' : 'h1','a', 'hello' : 'h2','a2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example that you have given, you have used one list as the keys to your dictionary, and the other list as the values for your dictionary.

If this is what you want, then you can combine the list into key,value pairs using `zip` as follows:

```py
a_list = ['h1','a'],['h2' ,'a2']
b_list = ['hi', 'hello']
d = {}
for k,v in zip(b_list,a_list):
    d[k] = v
print(d)
```

The result:

```py
{'hi': ['h1', 'a'], 'hello': ['h2', 'a2']}
```

---

As a side note, in the example you gave, `a_list` is actually a `tuple` of `lists`.

It will also work as a `list` of `lists`:

```py
a_list = [['h1','a'],['h2' ,'a2']]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `dict(zip(b_list, a_list))` suffice in this case?

Comment: @kuro Excellent!   Yes, i forgot that's one form of the `dict()`s constructor!

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is using dictionary [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> a_list = ['h1','a'],['h2' ,'a2']
>>> b_list = ['hi', 'hello']
>>> {x:y for x,y in zip(b_list,a_list)}
```

Output:

```
{'hi': ['h1', 'a'], 'hello': ['h2', 'a2']}
```